# AspNetCore2.0 Localization not working on HTML

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, localization

I have a problem in setting the localization in the View while it works when setting on the controller. Here are the steps i followed.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{            
     services.AddLocalization(option=>option.ResourcesPath="services.AddLocalization(options => options.ResourcesPath = "StringResources");");

     // Add application services.
     services.AddTransient<IEmailSender, EmailSender>();

     services.AddMvc()
             .AddViewLocalization(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.LanguageViewLocationExpanderFormat.Suffix);
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{            
     var supportedCultures = new[]
     {
           new CultureInfo("nb-NO"),
           new CultureInfo("en-US"),
           new CultureInfo("zh-CN"),               
     };
     app.UseRequestLocalization(new RequestLocalizationOptions
     {
           DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture("en-US"),
           // Formatting numbers, dates, etc.
           SupportedCultures = supportedCultures,
           // UI strings that we have localized.
           SupportedUICultures = supportedCultures
     });
     app.UseStaticFiles();            
}
```

and create a **`StringResources`** Folder added a file named **SharedResources.en-us.resx file.**

Created a controller as follows

```
public class AccountController : Controller
{
     private IStringLocalizer<SharedResources> _sharedLocalizer;

     public AccountController(
         IStringLocalizer<SharedResources> sharedLocalizer
     )
     {
         _sharedLocalizer = sharedLocalizer;
     }
}
```

the above works in controller but not in the view. My HTML is as follows,

```
@inject IHtmlLocalizer<SharedResources> SharedLocalizer;
<h1>@SharedLocalizer["LogInTo"]<br>
```

Output on the view right now is **LogInTo** whereas i am expecting it to be
**Logg inn**

Comment: It's not totally clear what your expected output will be. You define supported cultures as `en-us` and `zh-cn`, you create a `en-us` resource file, and you try to set the locale as `sv-se`, correct?

Comment: Could this be related to inconsistent naming somehow? SharedResource*s* vs SharedResource.<culture>.resx. Or is that a question-only-typo of yours? Weird if it works in controller but not in view

Comment: @Tewr Yes it is a typo, yes still i could not figure out

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Per chat we were able to figure out what the cause of this problem is.

Basically, the weird part about this was that the `IStringLocalizer` appeared to work, while the `IHtmlLocalizer` did not. This generally should not be an issue since `IHtmlLocalizer` is actually just a very thin layer around the string localizer which adds some HTML encoding, to make it useful within Razor views.

So the other angle we looked at was whether there was any other code in the controller that should affect how the localizers worked. Previous test code had the current thread locale set explicitly, so we had to make sure that this still being around was *not* the issue, and that the localizer in both the controller and the view were executing within the same context.

This left us with the localizer themselves. The way the the generic localizers work is that they use the generic type argument for the naming to resolve the resource source. The fact that one localizer was able to produce the strings from the resource file, while the other was unable to resolve *any* string meant, that both localizers were apparently using a different resource file.

And that was indeed the problem: The `IHtmlLocalizer<SharedResources>` that got injected in the view was referencing a different `SharedResources` type than the `IStringLocalizer<SharedResources>` injected into the view.

Unless there are explicit `@using` directives within the view, the Razor engine will respect the using directives within the `_ViewImports.cshtml` file. It’s likely that a `@using` in that file gave access to a `SharedResources` type which was within a *different* namespace than the expected type. So Razor did not complain since it could find a type with that name, but it ended up being a different one.

Just like in normal C# code, you can always specify types using the full namespace. This avoids conflicts when there are types with the same name in different namespaces. So the safest way to avoid this problem was to change the `@inject` directive to use the full namespace for the `SharedResources` type:

```
@inject IHtmlLocalizer<Utilities.Resources.SharedResources> SharedLocalizer
```

Comment: Great answer, after spending a couple of hours debugging this error i found your solution that work great.